# Accessing a Page's control properties from another page's code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a **Page** called `Page1`.

I have another **Page** called `Page2` with a **TextBox** called `TextBox1`.

I want to manipulate the **Text** of `TextBox1` using `Page1`'s code.

I have made `TextBox1` **public** using the `x:FieldModifier="public"` code in XAML.
I have then tried to use `Page2.TextBox1.Text = x`, with no success.
How do I do this?

I did not provide any more code, but please tell me if this is not sufficient.

Comment: Page2 is a class, you need to make a variable for that class.  In Page1, when Page2 is initialized, store it in a variable, then you can update Page2's textbox with the variable.  Page2 page2 = new Page2();     page2.TextBox1.Text = "my new text";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is in the comments.  This is posted in case anyone else comes across this

Page2 is a class, you need to make a variable for that class. In Page1, when Page2 is initialized, store it in a variable, then you can update Page2's textbox with the variable.

```
Page2 page2 = new Page2(); 
page2.TextBox1.Text = "my new text";
```